# css clear: both; won't work with position: absolute

Tags: css

I have html setup where one of the elements needs to have `position: absolute;` so that the future children can be absolutely positioned. Positioning of the children seems to work file with `position: absolute;` But for some reason, the image that should appear right below the title appears to the right of the title. I have spent a few hours pondering this. I have also tried adding `position: relative;` to the div with `hot_spot_item` as class, but that wasn't fruitful. If you remove the `position: absolute;` on `.hot-spot-wrapper` you'll notice that image aligns right below the title, but that messes with the absolute positioning of the children.

Any help is appreaciated.

http://jsbin.com/ocetas/1/edit

**EDIT**

**@jkinz** thanks for the detailed reply. Your solution would work, if I could figure out that the title and the map are together and they both have same alightment. The problem is a bit more complex merely because of the way they do things here.

- HTML is built on the server side based on an XML configuration that the business folks use to author the page.
- This xml configuration treats the title and the map as two separate entities.
- This xml configuration is parsed on the server side item by item and put through a freemarker template that generates html for that particular item.
- Ergo, the html for the title is generated separately from the html for the map making my life miserable.
- This is one of many things business authors can do with the xml configuration.
- Therefore you can see that if It would be hard for me to detect that this is the kind of xml definition they put in place and wrap the title and the map together so I can align them.
- Also, they can individually control the horizontal alignment of the title and map.

P.S. I am in a classic case of "design production detachment syndrome". For the longest time I thought this wasn't possible in Software Industry. The architects designed and implemented the entire backend in a shop that has no experience in developing web-based products without having a UI developer on board for two years and then they brought me in for doing the UI and they don't want me complaining how crappy a method  that is to develop software.  Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: The `<div class="block">` that contains `<div class="hot-spot-wrapper">` is floated right. Is that what you're referring to? http://jsbin.com/uzecim/1/edit

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. But the image is supposed to show up right below the title. If I remove that it seems to work, but is there a way so that I can have the `float: right;` and still get the image to render properly ?

Comment: You can't simultaneously float the image and not float it. What are you trying to achieve by floating it? Maybe there is an another method of achieving that.

Comment: You are probably right. I am doing some weird swing style dynamic styling based on server side configuration, that's why I have all those inline styles. Anyway, I seemed to have hacked my way around, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have a position declared, the children can be absolutely positioned.

Positioning an element absolutely takes it out of normal documents flow (floating does not), so clear doesn't really mean anything since it is looking to it's closest parent with a declared position (or the window if there is none).

In your case, a parent element with a position:relative should work. That will allow you to clear the parent and have absolutely positioned child elements.

*Edit after seeing the JSBin link*

So it looks like you're attempting to place markers on a map. I did this a bit differently, here is my approach: http://jsfiddle.net/sZq4d/

***HTML***

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
    <p>Place a marker on the map</p>
    <div class="map">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        <div id="place1" class="marker" title="A nice pop-over tooltip">
            P1
        </div>
        <div id="place2" class="marker" title="This is place 2">
            P2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.map-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}
.map-wrapper > p {
    text-align: center;
}
.map {
    /* background can be removed, height and width should match that of your map  image*/
    background-color:#eee;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
.marker {
    /* All common marker styles go here */
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
/* I'm using pixels here, if want a more responsive style, use percentages, that way   when the map scales, the markers stay in the appropriate place*/
#place1 {
    left: 20px;
    top: 100px;
} 
#place2 {
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 150px;
}
```

Comment: But as you see if you add `position: relative;` to the parent, image is still stuck on the right.

Comment: So it looks like  you are trying to place markers on a map is that correct? I would approach it differently. Here is what I would do: http://jsfiddle.net/sZq4d/

Comment: Thanks for the help, checkout my reply.